# Doxygen -- Single Comment Block for Multiple Functions

Tags: c++, comments, doxygen

Are you able to use a single commenting block to comment multiple functions in doxygen? Below is a simple example that does not work. Can I do something similar to get what I want?

file.cpp

```
#include file.h

/// @name FunsGroupedInDoxygen
///@{
/**
 * @brief  Documentation for 2 functions
 * @param  aParam A Parameter
 * @retval 0 will always be returned
 */
int fun1(int aParam) {return 0;}
int fun2(int aParam) {return 0;}
///@}
```

file.h

```
int fun1(int aParam);
int fun2(int aParam);
```

Doxygen output:

warning: Member fun2(int aParam) (function) of file file.h is not documented.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a reason for why you wouldn't just do them separately. Why would you use the same documentation for two functions? If they aren't different enough to warrant different descriptions then why are they two separate functions?

Comment: @Tuffwer Fair enough. Let me give you a specific example. In some of the libraries that I use, there are functions that control specific hardware pins. These functions can differ only on the target output. In mocking these functions, I would want to group them together and their documentation would be virtually identical. Perhaps you would want one documentation line to be different for each one.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, if the output needs to be different because it's working with hardware instead of entirely in software.  In that case I'd shoot for more of a hybrid and try to describe the family of functions with one block, but as an end user I still think I'd want at least one line explaining what the specific output target of the specific function was.  Thanks for explaining your situation I've never dealt with code that interacts at the hardware level (a good use case to keep in mind for similar questions), perhaps it's time to pick up a raspberry pi.

Comment: @Tuffwer I do like the sound of your approach. When I have tried to do it thusfar, I have been largely unsuccessful.

Answer (score 21):

Looking at grouping in the [Doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) here there are several methods you can use.  The one that I think best fits the situation is called Member Groups.

You can define a member group using one of two styles:

```
///@{ 
  ...
///@}
```

or

```
/**@{*/ 
  ... 
/**@}*/
```

An example of this would be:

```
/** @name FunctionGroup
 * @brief  Documentation for 2 functions
 * @param  aParam A Parameter
 * @retval 0 will always be returned
 */
///@{
//* fun1 specific description */
int fun1(int aParam) {return 0;}
//* fun2 specific description */
int fun2(int aParam) {return 0;}
///@}
```

This allows you to define a group that you can provide a generic description for and still lets you drop a comment specific to each function in the created doxygen files.

I don't have doxygen installed on the computer I'm on and can't test this code directly, however if follows the example from group2 of the member groups section on the documentation, the compiled output from that example is [shown here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/memgrp/html/class_test.html), which hopefully is the output you desire.

### Edit:

After testing the previous did work for me but only when I set the desired extraction mode to All Entities (EXTRACT_ALL = YES in the doxyfile).  It would be better to only use actually documented entities so I spent some time trying a different approach from the above mentioned documentation.

file.h:

```
/**
 * \defgroup FunctionGroup A Group of Functions
 * @brief Documentation for 2 functions
 * @param aParam A Parameter
 * @retval 0 will always be returned
 * @{
 */ 
int fun1(int aParam);
int fun2(int aParam);
 /** @} */
```

file.cpp:

```
#include file.h

/** @ingroup FunctionGroup
 * @brief fun1 specific description
 */
 int fun1(int aParam){
    return 0;
 }
/** @ingroup FunctionGroup
 * @brief fun2 specific description
 */
 int fun2(int aParam){
    return 0;
 }
```

Here is an image of the output I get when I run Doxygen on those two files:
[image: output of doxygen files]

I used the doxywizard on a windows machine my doxyfile generated by this is [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BVj7wEUf).

Comment: Doxygen is telling me:


temp/file.h:18: warning: Member fun1(int aParam) (function) of file file.h is not documented.
temp/file.h:19: warning: Member fun2(int aParam) (function) of file file.h is not documented.

As far as I can tell, all of the examples deal with member functions inside of a class, not stand alone functions.

Comment: I'll go through it later at home when I can get to my machine with Doxygen installed and see if I can hammer something out.

Comment: @Napthali Okay I added another way that seems to work using what should be essentially default Doxygen configuration.  Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I also had set set `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` to `YES`.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure about a single comment block, but a concise and easy way to do this is to use `@copydoc` ([reference here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc)), e.g:

```
/**
 * @brief Brief description
 * @param aParam A parameter
 */
void foo(int aParam) {}

/// @copydoc foo(int)
void bar(int aParam) {}

/**
 * @copydoc foo(int)
 */
void baz(int aParam) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` option has the effect that you want.  It’s relatively harmless to enable globally since, even with `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS` set, undocumented members in a member group will appear (only) in the summary table for the page.

Note that “member subgroups” apply to `\defgroup` groups as well as to classes and namespaces.